# Frobenius morphism associated to field extension

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, finite-fields, extension-field

I've got a field extension $F_{q^n} / F_q$ of degree n and the Frobenius morphism $f$: $ x \to x^q$ associated to $F_{q^n} / F_q$. Let m be an integer dividing n.

In terms of $f$, what's an expression of the Frobenius morphism associated to $F_{q^n} / F_{q^m}$?

Comment: You know that the Frobenius of $F_{q^n}/F_{q^m}$ is given by $x \mapsto x^{q^n}$ by the same fact you used.
Now you can compute easily, how this is related to $f$. The divisibility is only needed to ensure that $F_{q^m}$ is a subfield of $F_{q^n}$.

Comment: $f^m = f\circ ... \circ f$